# Login Details using Content Provider, brings many loop

Tags: android, authentication

I want to create a `Toast` Text (about I haven't registered in the database) on the Login `Activity`. However, there is a problem when I put this `Toast` text. If I put it inside a while loop `Cursor.MoveToNext()`, it will loop as many times as many entries it has.

**Inside the loop**

```
 if(cursor!=null)
                    {
                        {
                            int i = 0;
                            while(cursor.moveToNext())
                            {
                                if(cursor.getString(i).equals(input_email) && cursor.getString(i).equals(input_password))
                                {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Udah masuk belum " );
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Intent intent =new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                    i = i + 1;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You haven't Registered yet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Intent intent =new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                            cursor.close();
                        }
                    }
```

But when I putted outside of the loop, it brings error. Do you know what is the solution of this one?

**Outside the loop**

```
       String [] projection ={ServiceProvidersContract.Columns.SEmail, ServiceProvidersContract.Columns.spPassword};
                   Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ServiceProvidersContract.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);

                   Log.d(TAG, "Checking Cursor" + cursor );
                    if(cursor!=null)
                    {
                        {
                            int i = 0;
                            while(cursor.moveToNext())
                            {
                                if(cursor.getString(i).equals(input_email) && cursor.getString(i).equals(input_password))
                                {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Udah masuk belum " );
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Intent intent =new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                    i = i + 1;
                                }
                            }
                            cursor.close();
                            if(!cursor.getString(i).equals(input_email) && cursor.getString(i).equals(input_password))
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You haven't Registered yet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent intent =new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();

                            }
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: As you are iterating while loop you cusror is having say 100 values, so for all value if it does not enters if condition else will be executed so 100 times toast will be generated.

Comment: Yes I am sorry. I didn't put the For looping in here so that is why it could not working.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to clarify, I did finally login successfully in my login parts using For and While. 
The other problem is coming from the Toast Text ( where I couldn't put the failed Toast Text in the loop). This is my codes :

```
private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
private Button btnLogin, btnLinkToRegister;
private SessionManager session;
private EditText password, email;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);



        // Defining everything
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegister);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);


  //       Login button Click Event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver() ;

                String input_email = email.getText().toString().trim();
                String input_password = password.getText().toString().trim();
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: " + input_email  + input_password);

                // Check for empty data in the form
               if (!input_email.isEmpty() && !input_password.isEmpty()) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "onClick: if statement succeseful");

               //      checking from the database
                   String [] projection ={ServiceProvidersContract.Columns.SEmail, ServiceProvidersContract.Columns.spPassword};
                   Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ServiceProvidersContract.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);

                   Log.d(TAG, "Checking Cursor" + cursor );
                    if(cursor!=null)
                    {
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        while(cursor.moveToNext())
                        {
                            Log.d(TAG, "while process");
                            for(int i=0; i<cursor.getColumnCount(); i++)
                            {
                                Log.d(TAG, "for process " + cursor.getString(i));
                                if (cursor.getString(0).equals(input_email) && cursor.getString(1).equals(input_password)) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "if process");
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (!cursor.getString(0).equals(input_email) && cursor.getString(1).equals(input_password)) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "if process");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You haven't registered yet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                        cursor.close();
                    }
                } else {
                    // Prompt user to enter credentials
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

            btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view){
                    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
        });
    }
```

}